# What is the difference between a set that is countable and infinite and one that is countably infinite?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I am rereading my analysis notes and I came on this remark in the section on countability:

We have proved that Q is countable, and certainly Q is not ﬁnite, because N ⊆ Q. We
have not proved that Q is countably inﬁnite.

The way this is phrased suggests a difference between something being countably infinite and something being countable and infinite. Is there a difference?

Thanks.

Comment: Countable: there is an injection from the set to $\Bbb N$. Countably infinite: there is a bijection from the set to $\Bbb N$. Are these your definitions?

Comment: I should have read through my notes more carefully. It does not seem that "countable" is defined. I have:

A and B are equinumerous, A ≈ B, if there is a bijection f : A → B.

A is finite if either A = ∅
or there exists n ∈ N such that A ≈ {1, . . . , n }.

We call A countably inﬁnite (or denumerable) if A ≈ N. We call A uncountable if
it is inﬁnite but not countably inﬁnite.

Comment: Can you give an example of a set that is countable, infinite and not countably infinite?

Comment: @Ori If "$A$ is countable" means that there is a surjection $\mathbb{N}\to A$, then there are no such sets.  But you need to _prove_ that there are no such sets.

Comment: I feel this could be becoming confusing. At the end of the day the notions of countably infinite and countable+infinite are equivalent. However, depending on how you define them, you may have to prove that they are equivalent.

Comment: Ah, OK. Thank you for helping me see the subtlety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it may help, I will follow the exposition in Patrick Suppes, [Axiomatic set theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486616304) (1960 - Dover reprint).

Suppes starts with Tarski's definition of *finite* set [page 100] :

> **Definition 5**. [A set] $A$ is *finite* if and only if every non-empty family of subsets of $A$ has a minimal element.

An alternative definition is due to Dedekind [page 107] :

> **Definition 6**. A set is *Dedekind finite* if and only if it is not equipollent to any of its proper subsets.

Then we have :

> **Theorem 46**. If a set is finite then it is Dedekind finite.

Page 150 :

> **Definition 23**. A set is *infinite* if and only if it is not finite.
>
> **Theorem 38**. if $A$ is infinite and $A ≈ B$ then $B$ is infinite.
>
> **Theorem 39**. If $A \subseteq B$ and $A$ is infinite then $B$ is infinite.
>
> **Theorem 40**. A set $A$ is infinite if and only if for every natural number $n$ there is a subset of $A$ equipollent to $n$.
>
> **Theorem 41**. The set $\omega$ of natural numbers is infinite.

Page 151 :

> **Definition 24**. A set is *denumerable* [also : *countable infinite*] if and only if it is equipollent to the set $\omega$ of all natural numbers.

Page 152 :

> As an immediate consequence of Theorems 38 and 41 we have:
>
> **Theorem 43**. Every denumerable set is infinite.
>
> **Definition 25**. A set is Dedekind infinite if and only if it is not Dedekind finite.
>
> **Theorem 44**. A set is Dedekind infinite if and only if it has a proper subset equipollent to it.

---

*Comment*

We have to note the interplay between *definition* and *theorems* : stating the basic definition of *denumerable* set, Suppes is able to prove that a denumerable set is *infinite*.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. Finite sets are by definition countable, so countably infinite is used to clarify that the set in question, whilst countable, is not finite.

Comment: Makes sense, but then in the situation posed in the OP, what would be required to prove that Q is countably infinite beyond proving that it is countable and that it is not finite? Or is that statement just mistaken?

Comment: I'm not sure - I felt it would be best to clarify the usual conventions. I guess I'm secretly hoping that "not proved" should be "now proved"

Answer (score 1):

This is speculation, but perhaps your text means to say that, even if we have a surjection $\mathbb{N}\to S$, and we know that $S$ is not in bijection with any finite set, we still need to prove that there is a bijection $S\to\mathbb{N}$.  This is true, but it's good form to prove it.

Comment: Even so, the formulation does imply that at this point, despite proving that it is countable and not finite, nevertheless we still need to prove it countably infinite... which is strange

Comment: @Mathmo123 The point is that it depends on the definitions of these terms.  If we say that $S$ is finite if there is a bijection with a set of the form $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$, countable if there is a surjection $\mathbb{N}\to S$, and countably infinite if there is a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $S$, then it is indeed a theorem that needs proving to say that a non-finite countable set is countably infinite.

Comment: Right. But then it should say "We have not proved that a countable and infinite set is countably infinite" as it has nothing to do with Q

Comment: @Mathmo123 Without knowing the text/lecture, I can't really comment on matters of style.